# How to make Rails standard resource accept POST on update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rest, angularjs

I was stuck with AngularJS - Rails capability. *ngResource* sends POST requests both on *create* and *update*. I found solutions for this problem for *ngResource*, but I would like to solve it on Rails side. I think there are no any conflicts 'course *update* and *create* performs on different URIs

Answer (score 1):

You can change Rails resource to accept post method for update action.
However, I do not recommend this way because RESTful way of update has better to be `PUT` method, not `POST`

As you said, you found a soultion to send PUT request on ngResource.
I highly recommend that way.

From http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/05/16/angularjs-ngresource-tips-and-tricks/, 
ngResource does not support PUT out of the box, but it is **extremely easy to implement:**

```
var res = $resource('/your/url/:id', {foo: 'bar'}, {'put': {method: 
  'PUT', params: {foo: 'baz'}, isArray: false}});
```

Here is another discussion about it, and we better not to use `POST` for update again.

[PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest?rq=1)

Comment: The problem is ngResource does not distinguish between create and update actions while $save is called. It just appends ID to uri if it exists in object. Because of this I need to overwrite $save method in resource instance prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try overriding it in your `routes.rb` like this? I never tried it with the standard actions, but it might just work for you:

```
resources :users do
  post 'update', :on => :member 
end
```

Comment: If it conflicts with the other update method, you might add `resources :users, :except => :update do`